# How to install Ubuntu as main os?

Tags: system-installation

Just like in topic I want Ubuntu as main main OS the actual problem is I'm newbie to Unix system and I don't get all this mounting points (what they are for, which one I need use, what other does, etc.) I have 300Gb HDD and 3Gb of RAM. Can somebody help me?

Comment: So do you want to keep any partitions on your HDD? Otherwise you can just format your HDD, and install Ubuntu using an live CD or USB stick.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Simply use the entire disk. Go with the defaults, there is not need to customize the iinstaller defaults.

Comment: What do you mean by "as main OS"? How about you go over a [simple guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) and see if you feel any better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Start up Ubuntu using a Live CD or USB. If you're unsure of how to do this, there are plenty of resources on Google on how to do this.

Then, double-click on the Install Ubuntu xx.xx on the desktop.

Follow the steps. When it asks, choose to Format the Harddrive (or similar). It will check that you're sure.

If you do this without backup your files, you will NEVER get them back. So make sure to get whatever files you need before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I think he/she was looking for some pretty simple answers here and it feels like that it takes more time to answer a question in a rude way than to actually formulate a decent answer.

Lets address the questions shall we?

1. Ext is linux standard extended file system.
   -Ext3 is Extended File System 3 or third extended file system generally use Ext3 this is the most up to date version of the file system.

2.Concerning mounting points generally for main OS you mount to

/ = the root or first/primary directory of a hard drive

3. You have plenty of memory both virtual and physical for ubuntu
4. burn to disc or use Unetbootin to make a bootable usb then insert restart computer follow prompts for full installation ie. erase everything and install ubuntu...follow more setup prompts...enjoy.